# Каким образом можно сэкономить место на физическом диске при виртуализации нескольких Windows серверов на платформе Vmware Esxi?

Tags: vmware

Каким образом можно сэкономить место на физическом диске при виртуализации нескольких Windows серверов на платформе Vmware Esxi

Answer (score 1):

есть такой механизм под названием [Linked clone](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-BA264A65-C50F-4345-A787-DCC5C5324DD1.html), который поможет вам.

Представьте, у вас есть 10 VM Win10. каждая весит 10 20Гб. Было бы логичнее дедублицировать общую память или использовать однаковые куски. 
Для этого вы создаете базовую машину и от него создаете Linked clone машину, которая будет считывать данные из базовой машины + своя дельта. То, что вам нужно.

Готовый скрипт на PowerShell

```
$viUserName = "user"
$viPassword = "pswd"
$vCenter = "vcenter.server"

Add-PSSnapin VMWare.VimAutomation.Core

$viCredential = (New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential `
$viUserName, `
(ConvertTo-SecureString $viPassword -AsPlainText -Force))

function Create-LinkedClone{
    Param
    (
        [string] $sourceVMName,
        [string] $sourceSnapshotName = "Base",
        [int] $cntVMs = 1
    )

    if ($cntVMs -ge 10)
    {
        Write-Error "Maximum number of clones eq 9"
    }

    $server = Connect-VIServer -Server $vc -Credential $viCredential -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
    $sourceVM = Get-VM -Name "$sourceVMName$suffix"
    $sourceSnapshot = Get-Snapshot -VM $sourceVM -Name $sourceSnapshotName
    $vmResourcePool = Get-ResourcePool -VM $sourceVM
    $vmDatastore = Get-Datastore -VM $sourceVM

    for($id=1; $id -le $cntVMs; $id++)
    {
        $cloneVMName = $sourceVMName.Substring(0, $sourceVMName.Length - 2) + "c" +  $id.ToString() + $suffix
        New-VM -Name $cloneVMName -VM $sourceVM -LinkedClone -ReferenceSnapshot $sourceSnapshot -ResourcePool $vmResourcePool -Datastore $vmDatastore
        New-Snapshot -Name $sourceSnapshot -VM $cloneVMName 
    }

    Disconnect-VIServer -Server $server -Confirm:$false
}

$vc = $vCenter

Create-LinkedClone "lConeName" -cntVMs 2
```